# How to split or remove excess letters/objects in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

output ==> ['s', 't', 'u', 'f', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'y']

this is the output I get, how can I get rid of one of the y letters?

Comment: What is the logic here?  Do you want to remove all duplicates, or something else?

Comment: I mean I just want to make a program just to be able to select an object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are trying to remove duplicates from your list.

So, here is an example code snippet:

```
list_With_Duplicates = ['s', 't', 'u', 'f', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'y']
list_Without_Duplicates = list(dict.fromkeys(list_With_Duplicates))

print(list_Without_Duplicates)
#Output is ['s', 't', 'u', 'f', 'w', 'x', 'y']
```